# How to make own .NET dll global?

Tags: .net, dll

I made a .net dll (Class Library) which is working together with my EXE if it is in the same folder. But is there a way to make the DLL "global" so it is installed somewhere on the system and I can still use it with my exe?

In the VB6 and activex era I used regsvr32 - Is there something similar to regsvr32 but for .net dlls ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to publish/install your assembly to the Global Assembly Cache. See this link for a [how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Global Assembly Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can refer the DLL from installed path.

Other wise you can use **[GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)**